# Enable only Java working sets in IWorkingSetSelectionDialog

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, working-set

I am currently using a IWorkingSetSelectionDialog created by a IWorkingSetManager. By default, clicking on the "new..." button in this dialog asks the user which type of working set should be created. But I would like to restrict to Java working sets, as in Package Explorer. Anyone know how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you use the:

```
public IWorkingSetSelectionDialog createWorkingSetSelectionDialog(
        Shell parentShell, boolean multi, String[] workingsSetIds)
```

method and specify the Java working set id (`org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaWorkingSetPage` in the final parameter:

```
new String [] {"org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaWorkingSetPage"}
```

you will get what you want.